# FedEx Address Validation API returning inconsistent response messages (SYSTEM.UNKNOWN.ERROR)

Tags: c#, json, rest, fedex

I've been successfully getting return messages from the FedEx Address Validation API using C# and REST, but have been getting inconsistent JSON response messages.

Sometimes I will send identical request messages (generating and using a new OAuth Token each time) back to back, and one time will receive a successful response containing information about the address, then after sending another request right after it will return an error code of "SYSTEM.UNEXPECTED.ERROR".

I also sometimes (rarely) receive "SERVICE.UNAVAILABLE.EXCEPTION" which the documentation says "the service is currently unavailable, we are working to fix the issue, please check back later". I cannot seem to find any sort of pattern in when the error messages are returned, especially since I am passing identical input requests and getting different responses at random.

One of the FedEx employees said to check the service I'm using to communicate with the API; but I have heard nothing about REST being unreliable, and my request message is identical to the schema included in FedEx's documentation. I included a picture (I'm new here and don't have 10 rep points yet so it forced my image into a link - my apologies) of my code that sends the request, I would be happy to include any other information that might help! Thanks!

EDIT - Below is the code for the `validateAddressAPI()` method that calls the FedEx address validation API - it accepts 2 strings as input: an Oauth2.0 Token and a string input that contains a JSON request message. The code that sets up the JSON input request message and calls `validateAddressAPI()` is shown below.

```
    string validateAddressAPI(string token, string input)
    // INPUTS - 
    //      token - Oauth 2.0 token generated by calling generateOauthTokenAPI() that is needed to use the Address Validation API
    //      input - Pre-formatted JSON string representing the address to be validated
    // OUTPUTS - 
    //      Return values:
    //          - Classification of inputted address (RESIDENTIAL / BUSINESS)
    //          - "UNEXPECTED ERROR" if API call returns SYSTEM.UNEXPECTED.ERROR (signals to main function to stay in the while loop that handles this error)
    //          - An empty string if unexpected functionality occurs 
    {
        string errorMessage = "";

        // Set up API request message
        var client = new RestClient("https://apis-sandbox.fedex.com/address/v1/addresses/resolve");
        var request = new RestRequest("/", Method.Post);
        string authorization_value = "Bearer " + token;
        request.AddHeader("authorization", authorization_value);
        request.AddHeader("x-locale", "en_US");
        request.AddHeader("content-Type", "application/json");
        request.AddParameter("", input, ParameterType.RequestBody);


        // Execute API Call and store response in a string (responseString)
        RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        string? responseString = response.Content;
        Console.WriteLine("Address Validation API Response: " + responseString);
```

```
                // Populate a new AddressInput() class object with input information ------------------------------
            Address address1 = new Address()
            {
                streetLines = new string[] { addr1, addr2 },
                city = city,
                stateOrProvinceCode = state,
                postalCode = zip,
                countryCode = countryCode
            };

            Addressestovalidate addressestovalidate1 = new Addressestovalidate()
            {
                address = address1
            };

            AddressInput addressInput1 = new AddressInput()
            {
                addressesToValidate = new Addressestovalidate[] { addressestovalidate1 }
            };
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


            // Convert to a JSON string using serialization of the class instance
            string addressJSONstring = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(addressInput1);
            Console.WriteLine("addressJSONstring:::: " + addressJSONstring);

            //string initialJSONstringheader = @"{""inEffectAsOfTimestamp"": ""2022 - 05 - 05"",""validateAddressControlParameters"": {""includeResolutionTokens"": true},";

            // Generate an access token using FedEx Developer Account credentials
            var access_token = generateOauthTokenAPI(client_id, client_secret);

            // Make initial call to the FedEx Address Validation API
            var result = validateAddressAPI(access_token, addressJSONstring);
```

Comment: We won't know how to make the changes to your existing code base without seeing your original code. Please post a [mre], and fully explain what needs to be modified. Keyword: MINIMAL, not your entire project

Comment: Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, formatting my code snippets now!

Comment: How did you get your "ClientID" and "ClientSecret"? What URL did you use to request them?